# "Read more" in Wordpress won't change

Tags: wordpress, button

the question seems to be very simple as google delivers thousands of results but I edited 22 wordpress .php files and not a single files contains the words "Read more" but still on my frontpage of wordpress (index.php) it says "Read more" on the buttons. I can't help, I've searched in over 150 files of my wordpress installation too and the theme, no "Read more" but it still appears....ARGH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read more is being used by `the_content()` Look in your index file for something like `the_content('Read More...);` and either change the text or delete it all together.

Comment: I already did, but in my entire wordpress installation the words "Read more" are deleted. They literally can't be used anywhere anymore :)

Comment: Can you link to your site?

Comment: In at text editor do a search for `<div class="link">` this is the div the read more link is coming from.